# Exponential function for Linear operators. Convergence of series of linear operators.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra

I am on my first course in Real analysis and have limited mathematical background except for standard courses in calculus/linear algebra.

So I have been given this function $\exp(B):\mathcal{L}(U) \to \mathcal{L}(U)$ which is defined as follows for $B \in  \mathcal{L}(U)$ :

$$\exp(B)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B^k}{k!}$$

Here, U is a Banach space and $\mathcal{L}(U,U)$  the space of bounded linear operators from U to U

My first goal is to show that the function $
\exp$ is well defined, in other words, that it

1. Always converges
2. Will always lie in $\mathcal{L}(U) : \exp(B) \in  \mathcal{L}(U)   \forall     B \in  \mathcal{L}(U)$

So for 1), I need to prove the convergence of the series

$$\exp(B)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B^k}{k!}=\frac{B^0}{0!}+\frac{B^1}{1!}+\frac{B^2}{2!}+......$$

My textbook contains a lot about the convergence of a linear operator itself, but when given a series of linear operators, I am stuck. I think I can use the fact that absolute convergence implies convergence, absolute convergence in this context meaning that the norm of the individual terms of the series converges:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \|\frac{B^k}{k!}\|\ =\|\frac{B^0}{0!}\|+\|\frac{B^1}{1!}\|+\|\frac{B^2}{2!}\|+...$$

I think the norm which is to be used is the operator norm $\|\cdot\|_\mathcal{L}$

I think that, since B is a bounded linear operator, the value of these terms will go to zero as k goes to infinity, but am completely unable to formalize it.

I am also wondering about basic calculation rules for norms and linear operators like, for instance, can I take the exponent outside the norm at the expense of getting something bigger, like :

$\|A^k\|_\mathcal{L} \le \|A\|_\mathcal{L}^k ?$

Sidenote:  I am new to math.stackexchange and have tried, to my best ability, to understand the rules of conduct on this forum. Now, I am aware that a similar question to mine was asked some years ago, but since it was seemingly left unanswered, and since it feels wrong to try to rekindle the discussion by posting my question as an "answer" below it, I have chosen to pose this as a new question.

---

Thanks for the answer. I gather from your answer that I am to use

$\|B^2\|=\|B\|\|B\|$,$\|B^3\|=\|B\|\|B\||B\|$ and so on in the terms of the series above.

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \|\frac{B^k}{k!}\|\ =\|I^U\|+\|B\|+1/{2!}\|B^2\|+1/{3!}\|B^3\|...
=\|I^U\|+\|B\|+1/{2!}\|\|B\|\|B\||+1/{3!}\|B\|\|B\||B\|+....$$

Still not sure how this will help me prove convergence, though.
Since U is Banach(complete) my understanding is that L(U) is also complete so that every absolutely convergent series will converge.

What about B being a bounded linear operator? What are the consequences of that as k approaches infinity?

Answer (score 1):

Note that for linear operators $U,V\in\mathcal{L}$,
\begin{align*}
\|UV\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|UVx\|\leq\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|U\|\|Vx\|=\|U\|\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|Vx\|=\|U\|\|V\|.
\end{align*}
Put $U=V=A$, one has $\|A^{2}\|\leq\|A\|^{2}$. For the rest that $\|A^{k}\|\leq\|A\|^{k}$ is just a matter of induction.

Comment: Thanks. Since U and hence L(U) is Banach I am pretty sure it is enough to show absolute convergence (in operator norm), so that what I´m really dealing with is showing convergence of a series of real numbers. Inserting ‖‖=‖‖‖‖ and so on doesn´t bring me very far, though. Does B being bounded have any further implications? And should the fact that the expression is recognizable as the ordinary Taylor expansion of e^x be used? (I know that a series is convergent if the sequence of the partial sums converge towards a function f(x)=e^x. ) Thanks again